# Navigation to a page and again to another page sequentially

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to open a page using `window.open` link to hit the servlet and from which I need to hit another servlet link, but the noticeable thing is that I cannot modify anything in those servlets.

Is it possible for me to do these two navigations from my first JSP page itself using Javascript or jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `window.onload` event to open your other servlet page.

Answer (score 0):

Inside serverJsp.jsp add this code at the end( after all your other code is done).

```
 response.sendRedirect("page2.jsp");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prabably try and avoid having a sequence like this exposed to the browser, can you do this all on the server side?

Having a web browser make all those requests would have a big performance hit if they are on a slow connection.

Alternatively, if you need to do this in the browser have the server return a http 301 status code with the location field in the header to refer to the next location you want the browser to hit.

Using the status code method would be the lightest weight on the browser, if you get involved with the browser having to interpret javascipt it will be a lot slower.

Comment: Actually my problem is in the second page it contains three frames and the third page is one which is one of that frame, I want to call the third page(one of the frame(main frame) in that second page) along with random parameters, and I need to display all those frames as the second pages looks like